# networking stopped working and I don't know why

Tags: networking, nfs

I'm afraid  I've shot myself in the foot.  For a very brief while, I had the wired ethernet working with a static IP, but in tryihng to get NFS setup to share files between a raspberry pi and Ubuntu, I cocked something up and now I have no network connection.  Being very new to linux and ubuntu, I have wandered into unknown territory.

My /etc/network/interfaces is....

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.155
gateway 192.168.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4
```

and my ifconfig looks like this....

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d0:50:99:90:ed:07  
          inet6 addr: fe80::d250:99ff:fe90:ed07/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1311 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:28 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:138824 (138.8 KB)  TX bytes:7142 (7.1 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:918 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:918 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:103298 (103.2 KB)  TX bytes:103298 (103.2 KB)
```

Unfortunately, I am not sure what else to send.  ubuntu is very new to me and I have found nothing on Google that helps me sort this out.  Maybe somebody can ask me some questions help me figure out how to diagnose this.

BTW, when I tryed setting up NFS, I used the following command....

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-common -y
```

Please help me diagnose this (or send any info that would help you help me).

thank you.
Charlie (the Linux newbee)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Add `auto eth0` above `iface eth0[...]`. Otherwise the interface won't come up automatically on boot.
2. It should say `dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4` - no comma.
3. <strike>Restart networking</strike> Bring the interface down, and then up again

   ```
   sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0
   ```

   Restarting `networking` is indeed deprecated and possibly interferes negatively with other services.

On that note, Ubuntu's default way of managing network connections is through NetworkManager. When using a graphical desktop, NM can be conveniently configured through its applet, or from the command line with `nmcli` or `nmtui`.

Comment: That did it.  Now If I can get NSF to work so I can access a couple Ubuntu folders from the rPi that I use to control my printers, I will be in good shape.    Thank you very much.

Comment: @chili555 is right. Though it worked for you, it's better not to restart networking. As far as your NFS issues go, this is a different subject. Please ask a separate question. But first, I suggest you browse the web. There are tons of how-tos and tutorials on the subject. Lastly, since your networking issue was solved, please accept either one of chili's or my answer. Otherwise the question will be kept as "unanswered". Thank you.

Comment: @CharlieRC Please see my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you amend your file to:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.155
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Restart the interface with:

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup -v eth0
```

Restarting networking is deprecated.